# get extended room info in asmack QuickBlox

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack, quickblox

How do I get extended room information (with number of occupants, room's subject, etc.) in asmack(without joining the room)? I'm using getRoomInfo() method, which sends packet to the server using disco#info protocol:

```
<iq from='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
    id='ik3vs715'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    type='get'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/>
</iq>
```

The problem is, I'm recieving standart packet, without additional info:

```
<iq from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    id='ik3vs715'
    to='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
    type='result'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'>
    <identity
        category='conference'
        name='A Dark Cave'
        type='text'/>
    <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
    <feature var='muc_passwordprotected'/>
    <feature var='muc_hidden'/>
    <feature var='muc_temporary'/>
    <feature var='muc_open'/>
    <feature var='muc_unmoderated'/>
    <feature var='muc_nonanonymous'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

The packet I want to recieve(with additional info) is like in the example:

```
<iq from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    id='ik3vs715'
    to='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
    type='result'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'>
    <identity
        category='conference'
        name='A Dark Cave'
        type='text'/>
    <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
    <feature var='muc_passwordprotected'/>
    <feature var='muc_hidden'/>
    <feature var='muc_temporary'/>
    <feature var='muc_open'/>
    <feature var='muc_unmoderated'/>
    <feature var='muc_nonanonymous'/>
    <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='result'>
      <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'>
        <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#roominfo</value>
      </field>
      <field var='muc#roominfo_description' 
             label='Description'>
        <value>The place for all good witches!</value>
      </field>
      <field var='muc#roominfo_changesubject' 
             label='Occupants May Change the Subject'>
        <value>true</value>
      </field>
      <field var='muc#roominfo_contactjid' 
             label='Contact Addresses'>
        <value>crone1@shakespeare.lit</value>
      </field>
      <field var='muc#roominfo_subject' 
             label='Current Discussion Topic'>
        <value>Spells</value>
      </field>
      <field var='muc#roomconfig_changesubject' 
             label='Subject can be modified'>
        <value>true</value>
      </field>
      <field var='muc#roominfo_occupants' 
             label='Number of occupants'>
        <value>3</value>
      </field>
      <field var='muc#roominfo_ldapgroup' 
             label='Associated LDAP Group'>
        <value>cn=witches,dc=shakespeare,dc=lit</value>
      </field>
      <field var='muc#roominfo_lang' 
             label='Language of discussion'>
        <value>en</value>
      </field>
      <field var='muc#roominfo_logs' 
             label='URL for discussion logs'>
        <value>http://www.shakespeare.lit/chatlogs/coven/</value>
      </field>
      <field var='muc#maxhistoryfetch'
             label='Maximum Number of History Messages Returned by Room'>
        <value>50</value>
      </field>
      <field var='muc#roominfo_pubsub' 
             label='Associated pubsub node'>
        <value>xmpp:pubsub.shakespeare.lit?;node=the-coven-node</value>
      </field>
    </x>
  </query>
</iq>
```

What do I do to get extended info about my room? I'm using QuickBlox API and their server Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately QuickBlox Chat server supports only short room info at the moment.

I propose you to use [CustomObjects](http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects) record to wrap Chat room and store any additional room info